# Wording for an application/sub-system that allows editing user profile pages

Tags: website-design, terminology

I am brainstorming for an application and I am struggling to get the terminology correct.

The application has a profile page which the user can edit and an admin page.
The users will have a profile page which is made public. (not editable for third parties)

How are such applications like this called, CMS? 
I think a CMS is bigger with no public user pages.

What is the best term for:

- The public profile page.
- The private user area.
- The admin page.

Comment: Can you update the question to be more specific? I'm left guessing as to what it is you're building, there is no info about what the admin page does... If we don't get more clarity on what stuff does, we can't help you giving it names. Also please improve the title, it also doesn't give any clues on what topic we're covering here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is that the users should share information about themselves, I would call it a "Profile" - so it would be a "profile page" and "edit profile".

The "private user area" you mention sounds like it's the main feature of the application - It could be called the landing page, news feed (like Facebook), or even dashboard if it's customizable.

The admin page should probably be called "Site configuration", "Settings", or similar, depending on the kind of settings on the page. Lawton suggestion for "Control panel" could also be relevant.

Based on the information you have given I think it would be categorized as a Social Networking site, since it's centered around user profiles (such as Facebook, Linkedin, etc.). Content Management Systems (CMS) on the other hand is centered around content (such as StackOverflow, or SlideShare).

Answer (score 0):

Often both users and admins have a "Control Panel" where they can change their settings. The Profile page is just called a profile.

Answer (score 0):

If we borow the terminology from SharePoint, the user area is called MySite. On MySite you have both publicly available information and private information, controlled by the site owner. Site owner set permission level to the rest of the organization on hers/his MySite. MySite host the user profile page, which contains user properties such as title, phone no, e-mail address and the like.

The admin page can be called "Site Settings", "Admin Page" or "Site Configuration".

But you could always do an open card sorting session with your target audience to get the labeling accurate to this organizations domain language.